# Solidity K error when I try to burn tokens in liquidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, binance

I'm trying to implement a function in solidity that burns tokens in liquidity. e.g I add 10k tokens to pancakeswap, after some sales I have 15k tokens in liquidity and I want to burn 5K, so I decided to implement a counter to keep trace of the number of sold tokens and burn them with this snippet.

```
function burnLiquidity() public onlyOwner returns (bool){
        _burn(_exchangeAddress, _toBurn);
        _toBurn = 0;
    }
function _burn(address account, uint amount) private {
        require(account != address(0), "BEP20: burn from the zero address");
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply .sub(amount);
        _rOwned[account] = _rOwned[account].sub(amount);
        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }
```

The burning goes through but after that it becomes impossible to buy new tokens as the pancake returns K error.

Comment: You have to sync the reserves and the balances after burning